# Google Public DNS vs OpenDNS, which do you prefer?

Tags: dns, opendns, google-dns

I would like my DNS to filter/alert me of potential bad websites. OpenDNS seems to be touting this as their best feature, but Google also seems to say their DNS is secure.

Speed does not concern me much, I can wait a few milliseconds longer for better security.

Which do you use? Oh by the way I am comparing Google DNS against OpenDNS Basic Plan (the free one).

Answer (score 2):

I just started using OpenDNS with filtering - it doesn't seem to catch *all* sites in a given blocked category but it does a reasonable job. If you're worried about kids or others stumbling upon inappropriate sites then you might want some additional filtering on their PCs or other devices.

Comment: And this is where [OpenDNS community](http://www.opendns.com/community/domaintagging) comes in

Answer (score 2):

The security that Google Public DNS touts is just about the DNS system itself, not anything like filtering bad websites.  I have been using OpenDNS since it started and haven't had any issues, but I also don't use it for the filtering, just reliable service and speed.